# Custom list in .buckconfig?

Tags: buck

I would like to have a property in my `.buckconfig` that is a custom list of strings. From [the docs](https://buckbuild.com/concept/buckconfig.html), I understand that this is supported.

Here is my `.buckconfig`:

```
[custom]
  key = a b c
```

Here is my `BUCK` file (for testing):

```
print read_config('custom', 'key')
# etc...
```

Ultimately I would like to use `read_config('custom', 'key')` to generate the `deps` list of a target.

But when I build, I get this error:

```
$ buck run :app
Warning raised by BUCK file parser: a b c
```

What is the error here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better or worse, Buck parses the [build file](https://buckbuild.com/concept/build_file.html) as python (with the python interpreter).  Because you used `print`, it's messing up that output (either BSER or JSON) so the [build file](https://buckbuild.com/concept/build_file.html) cannot be parsed.